# Query MySQL from PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

Is their a code were you can use Or in a mysql query?

I used this code to find some Emails from a reciver.

```
mysql_query("select * from Friends where Reciver like '%$term%'");
```

but i want to do a code like

```
mysql_query("select * from Friends where Reciver or Sender like '%$term%'");
```

my question is? is this right because when I try it it doesn't come up with anything?

If it isn't right could you say so and say why it isn't? i learn well from my mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you do it

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE Reciver LIKE '%$term%' OR Sender LIKE '%$term%'");
```

Answer (score 8):

1st of all. Check out the dangers of [SQL Injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

2nd try this query.

```
select * from Friends where Reciver LIKE '%$term%' OR Sender LIKE '%$term%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Friends where Reciver like '%$term%' or Sender like '%$term%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this query and for that your query should be like this:

```
select * from Friends where Reciver like '%$term%' or Sender like '%$term%'
```